# Do I need OAuth if I use HTTPS?

Tags: node.js, ssl, oauth, https

I'm building an Node API, together with a Javascript client Application.

I was wondering if there are benefits to implementing OAuth, if I am also using HTTPS.

What if I just send username + password on each request instead of implement OAuth?

As far as I know, HTTPS encrypt the client-server communcation. But I might be missing something importatn.

I'm not going to allow third-party apps to access my API.

Comment: are you supporting 3rd party apps? or other apps that you might want to allow to login through your service/access resources that belong to users that use your service?

Comment: No, there will be no 3rd party apps supported. Just me and my client app.

Comment: Then that's the answer to your question. OAuth is authorization framework. If you want to improve the security of your API, take a look at [hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk).

Answer (score 0):

OAuth is authorization framework, so you are not getting any security over your API calls by default, especially if you are using OAuth2 which is most likely the case. If you don't need to authorize third party apps, then you don't need it.

If you want to secure your API though, then take a look at [hawk](https://github.com/hueniverse/hawk), using just Basic authentication is a bit naive.